# Find value of specific key in multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

From a json feed I receive a multidimensional array like below. From this array I need some values from specific keys, like the value at [payment_url]. I'm aware I can just get the value with

```
 $arr['transactions'][0]['payment_url'];
```

But since the documentation is a bit 'concise' I'm not sure if there could be a response with an extra level.

Henche, I would like a function which I feed with the key name and returns the value unregarded on which level the key is. Something like

```
getValue($arr, 'payment_url');
```

How do I do this?

```
Array
(
[amount] => 2525
[client] => Array
    (
        [user_agent] => gingerphplib
    )

[created] => 2016-01-15T21:35:17.032535+00:00
[currency] => EUR
[description] => this is a description
[flags] => Array
    (
        [0] => is-test
    )

[id] => xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
[merchant_order_id] => 205
[modified] => 2016-01-15T21:35:17.734427+00:00
[project_id] => xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
[return_url] => http://path/to/return/url/test
[status] => new
[transactions] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 2525
                [balance] => test
                [created] => 2016-01-15T21:35:17.231677+00:00
                [currency] => EUR
                [description] => dit is een omschrijving met een enter
                [id] => xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
                [modified] => 2016-01-15T21:35:17.612664+00:00
                [payment_method] => ideal
                [payment_method_details] => Array
                    (
                        [issuer_id] => INGBNL2A
                    )

                [payment_url] => https://link/to/payment/
                [status] => new
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: And what should happen in case there is more than one transaction in the `transaction` array?

Comment: Thats not going to happen in my code. I'm not even sure if it is possible to do more transactions at once. Documentation doesn't say anything about that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "there could be a response with an extra level". Could you give us examples of what you think it may be other than `$arr['transactions'][0]['payment_url']`? That would help us design a function for you.

Comment: Is it the API described at https://www.gingerpayments.com/api#_orders ? And in case it is, why aren't you using the "official" php binding: https://github.com/gingerpayments/ginger-php ?  (There might be a reason, even a good one, so this is really a question....)

Comment: Here's an interesting solution as well: http://thereisamoduleforthat.com/content/dealing-deep-arrays-php - BUT PLEASE listen to all the commenters saying "why are you doing this", and "there's a better way", and "use the ginger official php binding"

Comment: @VolkerK wow thanks! I've never seen that and this seems much better documented. Let me explain. a Big dutch bank is offering this payment method. They offer a portal where you can do some configuration (webhook url, etc) and an 'api description', which is the same as the tutorial from your link, but the reference from your link is missing. 

Besides that they offer plugins for os commerce, magento, etc. But I have to implement it in a custom webshop. So I've studied those plugins and started coding, but now I have more info.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From a purely technical perspective you *could* do something like

```
<?php
$response = json_decode(data(), true);
$flat = flatten($response);

echo $flat['payment_url'], ' | ', $flat['issuer_id'];

function flatten(array $arr) {
    $rii = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr), RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY );
    foreach( $rii as $k=>$v) {
        $rv[$k] = $v;
    }
    return $rv;
}


function data() {
    return <<< eoj
[
  {
    "id": "1dc05e5f-c455-4f06-bc9f-37a2db3a75e1",
    "created": "2014-07-14T10:13:50.726519+00:00",
    "modified": "2014-07-14T10:13:51.593830+00:00",
    "merchant_order_id": "EXAMPLE001",
    "status": "new",
    "type": "payment",
    "amount": 995,
    "currency": "EUR",
    "description": "Example order #1",
    "return_url": "http://www.example.com/",
    "transactions": [
      {
        "id": "90b70bba-e298-4687-a2f2-095f7ebc9392",
        "created": "2014-07-14T10:13:51.082946+00:00",
        "modified": "2014-07-14T10:13:51.210838+00:00",
        "status": "new",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "amount": 995,
        "description": "Example order #1",
        "expiration_period": "P30D",
        "balance": "internal",
        "payment_method": "ideal",
        "payment_method_details": {
          "issuer_id": "INGBNL2A"
        },
        "payment_url": "https://api.gingerpayments.com/redirect/90b70bba-e298-4687-a2f2-095f7ebc9392/to/payment/"
      }
    ]
  }
]
eoj;
}
```

see http://docs.php.net/RecursiveIteratorIterator , http://docs.php.net/RecursiveArrayIterator

But I'm <strike>rather</strike> very suspicious about the reason for using something like this given in the question. I suggest you investigate the "problem" further and do *not* use this.